# Slow boot time after ubuntu 17.10 fresh install

Tags: boot, time

I have very slow boot time after installing 17.10. 
Here is result of this command.

```
   graphical.target @43.977s
└─multi-user.target @43.977s
  └─smbd.service @30.145s +1.690s
    └─nmbd.service @26.955s +3.188s
      └─network-online.target @26.947s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @19.864s +7.081s
          └─NetworkManager.service @13.646s +6.216s
            └─dbus.service @12.199s
              └─basic.target @12.197s
                └─sockets.target @12.196s
                  └─snapd.socket @12.187s +9ms
                    └─sysinit.target @12.141s
                      └─apparmor.service @4.220s +7.821s
                        └─local-fs.target @4.209s
                          └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @26.528s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @23.253s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @4.170s
                                └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.103s +67ms
                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @2.504s
                                    └─-.mount @2.454s
                                      └─system.slice @2.456s
                                        └─-.slice @2.454s`
```

`

Comment: `systemd-analyze blame` hides what is running in parallel, `systemd-analyze critical-chain` will help you to find the critical path.
`systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg` can be used to see it graphically.

Comment: Thank you I edited my post , added result of command. Also boot.svg is here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9CU5L57BTQ_OTNtdU80OWc4UDA/view?usp=sharing)